# Can't remove a table view row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try many way to remove a row in a table view but for now, none of these work.
I just want to remove a tableView row when the user applies a long pressure on it.

ChecklistViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CheckListViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

ChecklistViewController.m

```
@interface CheckListViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation CheckListViewController {
NSMutableDictionary *_checkFlag;
NSArray *_menuData;
NSMutableArray *_edit;
NSMutableArray *_inputCell;
NSInteger rowToremove;
NSIndexPath *theIndexPathe;
int _maxInputCell;
}

- (IBAction)barAddTapped:(id)sender {

if (_maxInputCell < 3){

_maxInputCell +=1;
[_inputCell addObject:[NSNull null]];
[self.tableView reloadData];

CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height -     self.tableView.frame.size.height);
[self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
_maxInputCell = 1;
_checkFlag = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
_inputCell =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:_maxInputCell];

for(int i=0;i<_maxInputCell;i++)
    [_inputCell addObject:[NSNull null]];

_menuData = @[
              @"Passeport",@"Carte membre",@"Carte d'embarquement",@"Visa",@"Autorisation",@"Meddicaments autorisés",@"Produits autorisés"];

_edit = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"text1",nil];

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:255 alpha:.6f];
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius=10.0f;
self.tableView.clipsToBounds=YES;

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.5; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
 }
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

NSLog(@"%d",[_menuData count] + _maxInputCell);
return [_menuData count] + _maxInputCell;
 }

 - (IBAction)returnKeyPressed:(id)sender {
 [sender resignFirstResponder];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell;
long textFieldIndex = indexPath.row - [_menuData count];

if(textFieldIndex>= 0 && textFieldIndex < _maxInputCell) {
    //Input cell
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"];
    UITextField *textField;

    if(!_inputCell[textFieldIndex]) {
        _inputCell[textFieldIndex] = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    }
    textField = _inputCell[textFieldIndex];
} else {
    //Label cell
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_menuData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

if(_checkFlag[indexPath]!=nil)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

return cell;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(_checkFlag[indexPath]!=nil) {
    [_checkFlag removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
}else _checkFlag[indexPath]=@"1";

[self.tableView reloadData];
return nil;
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
if (indexPath == nil) {
    NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
} else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && indexPath.row > 6) {
    NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Voulez-vous supprimer cette ligne ?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Annuler",nil];
    alert.tag = 70;
    [alert show];
    rowToremove = indexPath.row - 7;
    theIndexPathe = indexPath;
}
 else {
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %ld", (long)gestureRecognizer.state);
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView * )alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView.tag == 70){
    NSLog(@"Yeah, %ld",(unsigned long)[_inputCell count]) ;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [_inputCell removeObjectAtIndex:rowToremove];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPathe] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView.tag == 70){
    NSLog(@"Annuler, %ld",(long)rowToremove);

}
}

@end
```

If someone could help me,
thanks by advance.

Kind regards

Comment: the formatting alone makes it nearly impossible to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing the gesture in the tableview you should add the gesture in the cell if you want to get action on any particular cell

Your code will be something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    long textFieldIndex = indexPath.row - [_menuData count];

    if(textFieldIndex>= 0 && textFieldIndex < _maxInputCell) {
        //Input cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textCell"];
        UITextField *textField;

        if(!_inputCell[textFieldIndex]) {
            _inputCell[textFieldIndex] = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        }
        textField = _inputCell[textFieldIndex];
    } else {
        //Label cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_menuData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if(_checkFlag[indexPath]!=nil)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    //****
    //Added gesture UILongPressGestureRecognizer here instead of tableview

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.5; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    return cell;
}
```

and you can handle the 'handleLongPress' as you are doing in your old code

**Note:** If there is no requirement of setting long press delete tableview has default option also to delete the selected row, which will be look like this , slide to get the delete option

[image: Default delete tableview]

Code for the delete button can be like this :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}
```

Comment: I found the problem, it just forgot to add  `_maxInputCell -= 1;` on my clickedButtonAtIndex method. Rookie mistake. But I didn't know that tableview has default option to delete the selected row with a slide movement, I'm going to use this.
Thanks @Pyro

Answer (score 0):

Before removing a row, but after begin updates, you should also update your data source to return the (new) correct number of rows. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found my mistake. I have to add `_maxInputCell -= 1;` on my clickedButtonAtIndex method. Rookie mistake. Thanks to everyone who took his time to help me. 
Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you have implemented the UITableViewDelegate method for allowEditing, if you have not implemented it, please implement

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
      numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)    
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
  }
```

It will bring the delete option when swiping, but of course you can call this delegate method for long press gesture as well.